# My nest.js app give me problems connecting to remote database into an azure VM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a nest.js app that works well in local. It connect to a remote database in clevercloud and everything works well. Now I created a VM in Azure and the app says 'Unable to connect'.

Here is the message:

```
[Nest] 11704  - 08/18/2023, 6:16:09 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'4.227.196.53' (using password: YES)
    at Packet.asError (/home/jasidmartinez21/my_apps/portfolio-chat-api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
    at ClientHandshake.execute (/home/jasidmartinez21/my_apps/portfolio-chat-api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (/home/jasidmartinez21/my_apps/portfolio-chat-api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/jasidmartinez21/my_apps/portfolio-chat-api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/jasidmartinez21/my_apps/portfolio-chat-api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/jasidmartinez21/my_apps/portfolio-chat-api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
```

My app.module looks like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: process.env.HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT) || 3306,
      username: process.env.USER,
      password: process.env.PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DATABASE,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    MessagesModule,
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(process.cwd(), 'app'),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
  exports: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I already executed the `npm install` and created the .env file. The node version is the same as my local machine's.
Anyone knows what could be happning?

I tried to see if my app module is reading the env variables with a console.log into the OnModuleInit, but it prints nothing. I don't know if it's because it crashes before the initialization.

Comment: Have you tried using [`mysql` CLI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/mysql.html) tool to connect to that remote database? Does that work?

Comment: Yes. It connect with the mysql cli. And it also works well in local. The only possible reason that gives to my head is maybe a default configuration for azure VM that I'm not aware of.

Comment: If you can connect to the database using the CLI tool, then your database server is fine. You need to check your Nest app - maybe check the environment variables.